# Have an build problem for react-native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im create new a react-native project

`react-native init navigationApp--version 0.59.8`

But have build problems... When i try run (`react-native run-android`)

Console stay step: `app:installDebug` and have some errors in `npm` part.

I tried they step-step;

1.rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

2.`npm install` react-native@0.55.2 babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0

3.`npm install`

4.react-native run-android

λ react-native run-android

Scanning folders for symlinks in `C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\project\react-navigation\navigationApp\node_modules (55ms)`
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
<============-> 97% EXECUT¦NG [7m 40s]

> IDLE
>   IDLE
>   IDLE
>   IDLE
>   IDLE
>   :app:installDebug
>   IDLE
>   IDLE

```
λ npm start

> navigationApp@0.0.1 start C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\project\react-navigation\navigationApp
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\project\react-navigation\navigationApp\node_modules (49ms)
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
───┐
│
   │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.
   │
│
   │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to
   │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.
   │
│
   │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native
   │
│
   │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
───┘

Looking for JS files in
   C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\project\react-navigation\navigationApp


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
 ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\project\react-navigation\navigationApp\android\app\build\intermediates\blame\res\debug\multi-v2'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 11
npm ERR! navigationApp@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 11
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the navigationApp@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MONSTER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-31T07_51_31_477Z-debug.log
```

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8evS.png)
[CMD IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsdul.png)

Comment: try to run your project with administrator privilege. (right-click on cmd and choose Run as administrator)

Comment: try to clean your project and build again.

Comment: @AliSn How can i clean?

Answer (score 0):

you must clean your project as below

```
npm start -- --reset-cache

react-native run-android
```

Also, you can clear project android `gradlew` file,

```
cd/android
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: i did it but nothing changed